# Stop re-rendering mapped lists when parent state changes

Tags: javascript, react-native, rerender, usecallback, memo

How do I avoid mapped child components from re-rendering at `onParent` state change?

I have already tried `memo` in child component and `useCallback` in parent component to memoise function that updates the state with an empty array as dependencies. I have also tried to use `option?.id` as a key to each child component. None of these seem to work.

#### Parent.js

```js
// imports and stuff
const [passedAnswers, setPassedAnswers] = useState(item?.options);
  // const [showScore, setShowScore] = useState(false);
  console.log("===========Parent component called ======================");
  // const [correct, setCorrect] = useState(false);
  const changeAnswer = useCallback((id) => {
    setPassedAnswers((prev) =>
      prev.map(
        (el) => (el?.id === id ? { ...el, isSeclected: !el?.isSeclected } : el)
    
      )
    );
  }, []);
return (<>
 {
        passedAnswers?.map((option, index) => {
          return (
            <CheckBoxQuiz
              key={option?.id}
              value={option}
              index={index}
              isSelected={!!option?.isSeclected}
              changeAnswer={changeAnswer}
              disabled={answered}
      
            />
          );
        })
      }

</>)
```

#### QuizBox.js

```js
import React, { memo, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { ICONS } from "../../assets";
import { TouchableBloc } from "../../components/bloc";
import { theme } from "../../constants/theme";



function CheckBoxQuiz({
  value,

  isSelected = false,
  changeAnswer,
  disabled = false,

}) {
  const color =
    isSelected == true && value.isCorrect == true
      ? theme.COLORS.green
      : isSelected == false && value.isCorrect == true
      ? theme.COLORS.green
      : "red";


  console.log(`==child component called ${value.id}==`);

  return (
    <TouchableBloc
      // key=r{index}
      onPress={() => {
        changeAnswer(value?.id);
      }}
      disabled={disabled}
      containerStyle={{
        marginHorizontal: 0,
        flexDirection: "row",
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderColor: disabled
          ? color
          : isSelected
          ? theme.COLORS.green
          : "#E6E6E6",
        borderWidth: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: isSelected && "#FAFFF9",
        marginVertical: 5,
      }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          flexGrow: 0.98,
          flex: 1,
          fontFamily: theme.FONTS.PoppinsSemiBold,
          fontSize: 16,
        }}
      >
        {value?.value}
      </Text>
      <View
        style={{
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: disabled
            ? color
            : isSelected
            ? theme.COLORS.green
            : "#E8E8E8",
          borderRadius: 5,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
     
        {isSelected && (
          <Icon
            name="check"
            size={10}
            color={disabled ? color : theme.COLORS.green}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </TouchableBloc>
  );
}


export default memo(CheckBoxQuiz);
```

Comment: try React.memo for a child component with it you can control component rendering by passing the second argument

Comment: @Shubham hey man thanks for your answer . i already tried it it still updates all children